# Find duplicate column values across multiple workbooks, and extract columns row data to new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple Excel workbooks some having multiple worksheets.

I'm trying to export the duplicates across the workbooks into a new workbook using Column A of each workbook as the unique value. All the workbooks are in the same directory.

The following doesn't work for workbooks with multiple sheets and is not accurate for some workbooks.

```vb
Sub CheckDuplicateAcrossWorkbook()
    Dim fName As String, fPath As String, wb As Workbook, sh As Worksheet, i As Long
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    fPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    fName = Dir(fPath & "*.xls*")
    
    Do
        If fName <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fPath & fName)
            If sh.Range("B1") = "" Then
                sh.Range("A1") = "Source"
            End If
            wb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Offset(1).Copy sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)(2)
            With sh
                .Range(.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2), .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(, -1)) = fName
            End With
            wb.Close
        End If
        Set wb = Nothing
        fName = Dir
    Loop Until fName = ""
End Sub
```

The original code removes the first five rows and 8th row with the header being row 7.

```vb
Sub CheckDuplicateAcrossWorkbookOriginal()
    Dim fName As String, fPath As String, wb As Workbook, sh As Worksheet, i As Long
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    fPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    fName = Dir(fPath & "*.xls*")
    Do
        If fName <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fPath & fName)
            If sh.Range("B1") = "" Then
                wb.Sheets(1).Range("A7", Sheets(1).Cells(7, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Copy sh.Range("B1")
                sh.Range("A1") = "Source"
            End If
            wb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Offset(8).Copy sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)(2)
            With sh
                .Range(.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2), .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(, -1)) = fName
            End With
            wb.Close
        End If
        Set wb = Nothing
        fName = Dir
    Loop Until fName = ""    
    For i = sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
        If Application.CountIf(sh.Range("B:B"), sh.Cells(i, 2).Value) = 1 Then Rows(i).Delete
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through each sheet of the opened file, rather than just using the first one. Try this... note the addtion of `eSheet`.

```
Sub CheckDuplicateAcrossWorkbook()
Dim fName As String, fPath As String, wb As Workbook 
Dim sh As Worksheet, i As Long, eSheet As Worksheet
Set sh = ActiveSheet


fPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
fName = Dir(fPath & "*.xls*")
        Do
            If fName <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
                Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fPath & fName)
                
                    For Each eSheet In wb.Worksheets
                        If sh.Range("B1") = "" Then
                            sh.Range("A1") = "Source"
                        End If
                        eSheet.UsedRange.Offset(8).Copy sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)(2)
                    With sh
                        .Range(.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2), .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(, -1)) = fName
                    End With
                Next eSheet
                wb.Close
            End If
            Set wb = Nothing
            fName = Dir
        Loop Until fName = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: hey thanks for your input. i'm tried your suggestion however im having run-time error  1004 copy paste size on the following line though

`eSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1).Copy sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)(2)`

Comment: And you didn't get that error before?

Comment: yes that's correct

Comment: It's probably getting that error on one of the other sheets, perhaps the used range offset doesn't work, but the above code should fundamentally work if your problem is as you describe.

Comment: Add this line of code before the copy so you can see which sheet is causing the error.  `Debug.Print wb.Name & " " & eSheet.Name & " -- about to copy..."` (make sure you have the immediate window displayed in your VB editor).

Comment: Ive check the relevant sheet and remove the unnecessary but it seems the issue persist. Ive also check my output and it seems that even non duplicated are being copied over though. I guess somewhere in my code there's flaw :(

Comment: included original code for your reference and guide

Comment: my apologies, indeed i appreciate your guidance but i did not expect you to magically solve all the problems. i apologies that i didn't upvote too earlier on. Hopefully you'll accept my sincere apologies

Comment: @Kaju, thanks for the upvote. All is forgiven and my apologies for being a little impatient. I hope you resolve your issue. If you repost another question related to this, post a link here and I'll check it out.

Comment: I have post another question if you're interested to take a look too which is related and I have recoded.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69629416/duplicate-value-not-deleted/69630604#69630604] @pgSystemTester

Answer (score 1):

I feel like some people here won't like this solution, because it's not a coding solution, but this will work for you Kaiju.

[image]

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm

I don't know what kind of 'duplicate' you are trying to find, but when everything is merged together, you can do whatever you need to do. The merge process is pretty intuitive. Just follow the steps in the landing page, and you should get what you want.