# Deleting duplicate values

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to delete all duplicate rows based on Column B and leave only the unique rows.

It will leave one of the duplicate entries. I tried with > 1 and = 2.

```vb
Sub test1()

    Dim fName As String, fPath As String, wb As Workbook, sh As Worksheet, i As Long, lCopyLastRow As Long, lDestLastRow As Long
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    fPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    fName = Dir(fPath & "*.xls*")
    
    Do
        If fName <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
        
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fPath & fName)
            lCopyLastRow = wb.Sheets(1).Cells(wb.Sheets(1).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            lDestLastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
            wb.Sheets(1).Range("A2:AA1000" & lCopyLastRow).Copy sh.Range("B" & lDestLastRow)
            sh.Range("A1") = "Source"
            
            With sh
                .Range(.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2), .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(, -1)) = fName
            End With
            wb.Close
            
        End If
        
        Set wb = Nothing
        fName = Dir
        
    Loop Until fName = ""
    
    For i = sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
        If Application.CountIf(sh.Range("B:B"), sh.Cells(i, 2).Value) > 1 Then Rows(i).Delete
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You might find it's a bit easier with the native `Range.RemoveDuplicates`. You can specify the column to look at for dupes. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.removeduplicates

Comment: I've actually tried with the following code but issue still persist though `Range("A2:AA10000").CurrentRegion.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(2), Header:=xlYes`

Comment: Please, replace `Range("A2:AA1000" & lCopyLastRow).Copy` with `Range("A2:AA" & lCopyLastRow).Copy`...

Comment: This doesn't really solve the issue, just that it select the select column AA that's about it though

Comment: So you want to keep the values that are unique in the source data and remove all data that are non-unique?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is, that you `countIf` on the remaining rows - if you already deleted the "other" duplicates the first one is a unique value in the then remaining list.

So you have to count the occurences *before* deleting.

```vb
Sub removeNonUniqueRows()

Dim arrCountOccurences As Variant
ReDim arrCountOccurences(2 To sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count)

Dim i As Long
For i = 2 To sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    arrCountOccurences(i) = Application.CountIf(sh.Range("B:B"), sh.Cells(i, 2).Value)
Next

For i = sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
    If arrCountOccurences(i) > 1 Then sh.Rows(i).Delete
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like a good answer. Feel free to ignore this unsolicited advice: To my eye, the abbreviation "...Cnt" is a bit unsettling. The sub name was nice and descriptive.. why not follow suit and call your array something like dupeCount? We already know it's an array by the declaration, I don't think prefixing it "arr" makes much difference :)

Comment: hmmm - with arrays I indeed always use a prefix (like e.g. with worksheets (ws) as well). But you are right - `arrCountOccurences` would be a better name. `dupeCount` is not exactly correct - as I am counting the unique ones as well ;-)

Comment: Good point. That's probably why I always end up renaming my variables 100 times, trying to get the most accurate description ... !

Comment: me too - finding good names is so essential for good code.

Comment: I would agree this answer looks good, and I agree with CallumDA!